# Unix C++ starting a child process and monitoring its stdio

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, process, pthreads

In my C++ program, I need to start a very long running new process and monitor its I/O.  I cannot modify the source code of the program in question.

I was thinking of create a new thread and starting the process in it and sending the output continuously (which will be coming out asynchronously) to main thread.

My code for creating the process currently looks like this:

```
std::string SysExec::exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
        return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

However, if called from main thread, it will make the main program stop (because of `while (!feof(pipe))`). How should I modify this? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The obvious answer is "Don't run this code from the main thread; run it off in a separate thread that doesn't have anything else to do". That then leaves you with the problem of notifying the main thread when the output from the long-running program is complete, and providing the value (probably by some variable with a scope/duration that is not tied to the thread/function that executes the code shown).  What mechanisms are you using for coordinating other thread activity?  Can you not use one of those mechanisms for this task too?

Comment: That is also not the correct way to use `feof()`; you should simply use `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe)) result += buffer;`.  You mention 'continuously sending the output to the main thread' too, but that is a confusing concept.  Would you send packets as they arrive, each as a discrete message?  Or tell it that the string has grown longer?  Remember that the output will likely be sent in BUFSIZ chunks from the (unmodifiable child) program because it will likely be fully buffered.

Comment: "man poll" and "man fileno" should be enough to get you started on how to read from the pipe only when data is available to read. You could also do a fcntl() call with O_NONBLOCK flag to insure you never get stuck on a read call.  However, this has one issue - if you don't poll often enough, the other side of the pipe writing data will get blocked until you do.